# Receiving Google Drive Push Notifications

Tags: php, push-notification, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have been able to establish a channel to receive push notifications from Google Drive by using the method described here [Not receiving webhook notification from drive, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000884/not-receiving-webhook-notification-from-drive-why). I am receiving notifications and everything is working fine. My problem is that when I receive the push notifications, I am only getting this information:

```
Content-Length: 0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,br
Connection: Keep-alive
Host: www.domain.com
User-Agent: APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)
X-Goog-Channel-Expiration: Thu, 29 Dec 2016 00:00:00 GMT
X-Goog-Channel-Id: 01ecb23c-e718-8674-6ab3-623931741334
X-Goog-Message-Number: 2745870
X-Goog-Resource-Id: hw75x654x56jYhRNkfU5CFEXXXhtlj8
X-Goog-Resource-State: change
X-Goog-Resource-Uri: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes?includeRemoved=true&pageSize=100&pageToken=658&restrictToMyDrive=false&spaces=drive&alt=json
```

According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#receiving-notifications), there are some "Change" notifications messages that include a **request body**. Unfortunately, I have not been able to get the request body.

The script that handles the push notifications has the following logic:

```
$oldcontent = file_get_contents('notifications.txt');

$newnotsfile = fopen("notifications.txt", "w");

$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$requestBody = json_decode($post , TRUE); //convert JSON into array

$time = date("Y-M-d H:i:s", time());
fwrite($newnotsfile , "<br><br>---------------- │ Time: ".$time."<br><br>");

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    fwrite($newnotsfile , $name.": ".$value."<br>");
} 

fwrite($newnotsfile , $requestBody );
fwrite($newnotsfile , "<br><br>");

fwrite($newnotsfile , $oldcontent);
fclose($newnotsfile );

?>
```

I thought that by using `$post = file_get_contents('php://input');` I would capture the request body but the truth is that it is capturing nothing. If I understand correct, I should receive a **change** resource with the structure detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes). Is there something wrong that I'm doing or have I understood this wrong? I appreciate any insight that can be given and thanks in advance!

Comment: I have also this problem. Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: I haven't. I have no clue where to get guidance on this. Please, if you are able to find the answer, post an answer to this question.

Comment: I have also asked a question here. I will let you know if i find the solution

Comment: I have answered the question. Lemme know if you have any clarifications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is no request body which gets sent in the webhook notification. So as soon as changes arrive in the callback url, changes are to be fetched by making a get request to changes resource uri like below

```
Resource URI : https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes?includeRemoved=true&pageSize=100&pageToken=895&restrictToMyDrive=false&spaces=drive&alt=json
```

Or programatically changes can be fetched by using the below code

```
String pageToken = channelInfo.getCurrPageToken();
            List<Change> changes = service.changes().list(pageToken)
                    .execute().getChanges();
```

Google push notifications doc could have mentioned this clearly rather than mentioning that the changes come along in the request body which is the reason for confusion

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this. This makes so much sense. I will adapt the code snippet you provided to PHP syntax. This solves all the mystery.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the documentation - [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push), this describes how to use push notifications that inform your application when a resource changes.

#### Watch response

> If the watch request successfully creates a notification channel, it returns an HTTP `200 OK` status code.
>
> The message body of the watch response provides information about the notification channel you just created, as shown in the example below.

```
{
  "kind": "api#channel",
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab"", // ID you specified for this channel.
  "resourceId": "o3hgv1538sdjfh", // ID of the watched resource.
  "resourceUri": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/o3hgv1538sdjfh", // Version-specific ID of the watched resource.
  "token": "target=myApp-myFilesChannelDest", // Present only if one was provided.
  "expiration": 1426325213000, // Actual expiration time as Unix timestamp (in ms), if applicable.
}
```

And if you will check the Understanding the notification message format:

> Notification messages for Files and Changes are empty.

The docs also provided samples:

Change notification message for Files resources, which does not include a request body:

```
POST https://example.com/notifications // Your receiving URL.
Content-Type: application/json; utf-8
Content-Length: 0
X-Goog-Channel-ID: 4ba78bf0-6a47-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66
X-Goog-Channel-Token: 398348u3tu83ut8uu38
X-Goog-Channel-Expiration: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 01:13:52 GMT
X-Goog-Resource-ID:  ret08u3rv24htgh289g
X-Goog-Resource-URI: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/ret08u3rv24htgh289g
X-Goog-Resource-State:  update
X-Goog-Changed: content,properties
X-Goog-Message-Number: 10
```

Change notification message for Changes resources, which includes a request body:

```
POST https://example.com/notifications // Your receiving URL.
Content-Type: application/json; utf-8
Content-Length: 118
X-Goog-Channel-ID: 8bd90be9-3a58-3122-ab43-9823188a5b43
X-Goog-Channel-Token: 245t1234tt83trrt333
X-Goog-Channel-Expiration: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 01:13:52 GMT
X-Goog-Resource-ID:  ret987df98743md8g
X-Goog-Resource-URI: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes
X-Goog-Resource-State:  changed
X-Goog-Message-Number: 23

{
  "kind": "drive#changes"
}
```

#### Understanding Drive API notification events

> This section provides details on the notification messages you can receive when using push notifications with the Drive API.
>
> You can try out any of the events below at the [Push Notifications Playground](https://pushnotificationsplayground.appspot.com/) or download the source from [GitHub](https://github.com/googledrive/pushnotifications-playground).

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your helping efforts. I have already reviewed the information on the documentation, which seems you copied and pasted here. Have you been able to get a "Change notification message for Changes resources, which includes a request body"? If so, we would greatly appreciate if you can provide an example or guide us. Thanks!