# Webhook notifications for Google drive changes not received

Tags: java, notifications, google-drive-api, webhooks

I set up webhook notification for my service account following the below steps

1. **Generated private key for my service account under IAM in developer console**
2. **Added my callback domain under Domain verification in my application in the developers console**
3. **Used the below code to register the web hook for my application**

   ```
   java.io.File file = new java.io.File("/xyz.p12");
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
   PrivateKey serviceAccountPrivateKey = SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(), fis, "notasecret", "privatekey", "notasecret");

       JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
                           HttpTransport t = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
       GoogleCredential gc = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(t)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(serviceAccountPrivateKey)
        .setServiceAccountId("xyz")
        .setServiceAccountUser("abc")
        .build();
       Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(t, jsonFactory,null).setHttpRequestInitializer(gc)
        .setApplicationName("xyz").build();
       Channel channel = new Channel(); 
   String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); 
   System.out.println(" UID :: " + uid);
   channel.setId(uid);
   channel.setType("web_hook");
   channel.setAddress("--- Callback URL");
   StartPageToken pageToken = drive.changes().getStartPageToken().execute();
   Channel c = drive.changes().watch(pageToken.getStartPageToken(), channel).execute();
   ```

The code runs successfully and also I got a call to the webhook as part of the registration (may be).

But when I make changes to the drive files in the drive account which is integrated to my application, I don't get webhook notification. Can someone please tell me whether I am missing something in the process?

Btw I referred the code from this question

[Google push notifications - Unauthorized WebHook callback channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928758/google-push-notifications-unauthorized-webhook-callback-channel)

Answer (score 0):

Be noted that a watch request will not be successful unless the current user or service account owns or has permission to access this resource as stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#making-watch-requests).

> Each watchable Drive API resource has an associated watch method at a URI of the following form:
>
> `https://www.googleapis.com/apiName/apiVersion/resourcePath/watch`
>
> To set up a notification channel for messages about changes to a particular resource, send a `POST` request to the `watch` method for the resource.

You may also check on this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000884/not-receiving-webhook-notification-from-drive-why) which is also Not receiving webhook notification from Google Drive. Suggested action is to [delegate domain-wide authority to your service account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account).